# How to restore file permissions after wrong chown

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, catalina

All the files whether system files or drive are owned by root:wheel. What should I do?

Currently my Mac only opens in recovery mode.

I use mac OS Catalina

I stuck with recovery terminal what is the default ownership for all these files 
[image]

first I command this wrong command chown -R _www:_www /
 and destroyed my mac then i command on recovery terminal 
chown -R root /
which made things worse i think

I reinstalled Mac now I am stuck here. The old password doesn't work. Does Mac have a default name and password or what

Comment: Please read https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314 for the steps you need to take in order to get from Recovery Mode back into a useable system. You can't fix the damage done by your the `chmod` without it (and trying to fix it manually from Recovery Mode requires more explanations than we can provide).

Comment: this is a quite general answer I spent all the day already on the recovery mood

Comment: Look, we can't look onto your screen so we rely on your feedback to understand what's going on on your computer and in which state it is in. Unless you show us the errors you get (and not your assumptions about what is wrong) we won't be able to help you. So why don't you reboot into recovery mode, try to reinstall macOS from there (see the link in the comment above for how) and then, at the first moment something goes wrong/doesn't work, take a screenshot/picture and ask a new question based on that?

Comment: okay i will reinstall mac again and put screenshot here

Comment: @nohillside I reinstalled Mac but now I am stuck with name and password is there a default value

Comment: My icloud password and the old user password doesn't work

Comment: Where do they not work? Remember, we can‘t see your screen.

Answer (score 1):

The files and directories in `/` are always owned by root/wheel, there is nothing which seems wrong on your screenshot.

Comment: first I command this wrong command chown -R _www:_www / and destroyed my mac then i command on recovery terminal chown -R root / but now mac wouldn't open even in safe mode just recovery so i think something wrong